# Ionic Cordova Resources iOS Warning: Alpha Channel in App Icon

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

I'm encountering a warning while using `ionic cordova resources ios` command to generate app icons for my Ionic project. The warning message mentions that the source icon "resources/icon.png" contains an alpha channel and generated icons for iOS will not. The message suggests that Apple recommends avoiding transparency in app icons for iOS. I want to address this issue and generate iOS app icons without any transparency. How can I go about solving this?

```
WARN:     Source icon "resources/icon.png" contains alpha channel, generated icons for iOS will not.
  Apple recommends avoiding transparency. See the App Icon Human Interface Guidelines[1] for details. Any transparency in your icon will be filled in with white.

  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/

 Generated 47 resources for iOS
```

the size of icon.png is 1024x1024, and also its working for building Android application